# SetVisibility when use custom ListView

Tags: android

I've made a list view.
The list view works properly.
But the view list item is a xml file.
Which contains a imagView and a layer.
I want when the user clicks on the ImagView, the  layer to be displayed.
The problem is, is that when the user clicks ImagView was
Items layers 3 and 13, is displayed (twice).
I do not know what's the problem?
Somebody help?

custom_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImagView
    android:id="@+id/imagView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#0f0" />


   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00f" />

</LinearLayout>
```

.java

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder Holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        Holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.cystom_item, null);

        Holder.my_image= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagView);

        Holder.linear = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear2);

    } else
        Holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    Holder.my_image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (lastView == Holder.linear);
            else {

                if (lastView != null)
                    lastView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    Holder.linear.startAnimation(anim);
                    Holder.linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    lastView = Holder.linear;
                }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


public class ViewHolder
{

ImageView my_image;
LinearLayout linear;

}
```

Comment: Your code is not complete, please provide more code and explain your requirement correctly.

Comment: I updated my question
Look up the

Answer (score 0):

You wire the onClickListener multiple times:

```
Holder.linear1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()...
```

Set the clickListener only if it's a new Holder and not a recycled one.

You should notice that you don't have curly braces here:

```
else
   Holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

So everything after this line is executing.

Try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final ViewHolder Holder;

if (convertView == null) {
    Holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.cystom_item, null);

    Holder.my_image= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagView);

    Holder.linear = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear2);

} else
{
    Holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    Holder.my_image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if (lastView == Holder.linear);
        else {

            if (lastView != null)
                lastView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Holder.linear.startAnimation(anim);
                Holder.linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lastView = Holder.linear;
            }
    }
  });
 }

  return convertView;
 }
```

Comment: The problem is still the same

Comment: This line is Holder.my_image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() is executing weather it's a new view or a recycled one

Comment: Do notice that you don't have curly braces here:
else
        Holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

So everything after this line is executing.

Comment: The more explain?
What should I do ?

Comment: My problem is this:
When a user clicks on their ImageView  item 1
Layer was shown.
And the user was scrolling down
One other item of its layer displayed.(item 10)

Comment: When you click this code is executed multiple times:
if (lastView == Holder.linear);
        else {

            if (lastView != null)
                lastView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Holder.linear.startAnimation(anim);
                Holder.linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lastView = Holder.linear;
            }

Comment: No...if (lastView == Holder.linear);    
This means that  if the user double-clicked on an item
Animation  dont repeat    problem is something else

Comment: Again, the views in the adapter are recycled. So when you do this:
Holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

And then Holder.my_image.setOnClickListener, you're setting this event to a view which is already been wired.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think that you have placed the below if statement two times in the code, on the first time you done this with if statement and the second time, you initialized that in the else statement. I think that this is causing the doubling of the listitem views.

```js
if (lastView == Holder.linear);
```

You should try this:

```js
{

                if (lastView != null)
                    lastView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                else {

                    Holder.linear.startAnimation(anim);
                    Holder.linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    lastView = Holder.linear;
                }
            }
```

Instead of this:

```js
{

                if (lastView == Holder.linear);
                else {

                    if (lastView != null)
                        lastView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    Holder.linear.startAnimation(anim);
                    Holder.linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    lastView = Holder.linear;
                }
            }
```